# C# MemoryMappedFile not enough resources

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I'm doing operations on images. Some of these operations require me to create 3 different versions of the pixel data from the image and then later on combine them and do operantions on it.

For regular/small images the code works fine, I simply initialize my image raster data as `new int[size]`.

However for bigger images with a bigger resolution (600, 1200, ...) the `new int[size]` throws an OutOfMemoryException. Trying to allocate more than 2GB. However I've built it 64bit (not anycpu or 32bit).

To resolve this issue, I've tried to create a MemoryMappedFile in memory itself. This gave me out of resource also. Next I've tried to create a MemoryMappedFile but by first creating a file on disk and then creating a accessor over the complete file.

Still I'm facing the not enough resources with the temporary file on disk and the MemoryMappedFile/ViewAcessor.

Am I doing something wrong in the code below? I thought the MMF and Accessor would handle the virtual memory paging automagically.

```
      mmfPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
      // create a file on disk first
      using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(mmfPath))
      {
        var widthBytes = new byte[width * 4]; 
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
          fs.Write(widthBytes, 0, widthBytes.Length);
        }
      }

      // open the file on disk as a MMF
      _RasterData = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(mmfPath,
          FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
          Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
          0, // 0 to set te capacity to the size of the file on disk
            MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
      _RasterDataAccessor = _RasterData.CreateViewAccessor(); // <-- not enough memory resources
```

```
Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedView.CreateView(SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle memMappedFileHandle, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, Int64 offset, Int64 size)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor(Int64 offset, Int64 size, MemoryMappedFileAccess access)
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor()
...
```

In case I can resolve the problem above, I think I will later on run again on the same issue when I need to create a resulting bitmap out of the pixeldata again. (2GB limit).

The goal is working with big images (and temporary copies of its pixeldata for raster/raster operations).

The current issue is that I'm getting Out of memory resources with MemoryMappedFile. Where I thought this would resolve the 2GB limit and that Windows/Framework would handle the virtual memory paging issues.

(.NET Framework 4.8 - 64bit build.)

Comment: No, MMFs in 64-bit mode also have the 2GB restriction.  At least with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects you can get four times as much from an int[].  The WIC api supports very large image files, System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace in .NET.

Comment: @HansPassant would it help to create several views over a smaller portion of the file in order to bypass this 2GB limit? I guess that my "viewaccessor" is just too big? But this will still give me the issue when I finally need to construct a resulting bitmap...
Code isn't based on the WPF/Presentationcore... damn.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you're wanting to work with a simple representation where you can access all of the data as if it's in memory. No matter how you "say" this it's not going to work so you need to change to thinking of working with a streaming/cursor style of data access instead.

Comment: How large images are you processing? 2Gb should be fine up to ~500Mpixels, i.e. far higher than any normal image. For *very* large images, you should probably do some tiling, and possibly pyramids as well.

Comment: width * height * 4 at 600dpi = 1 982 467 872 bytes.
(*4 because integer colordata)
for example 3times allocating this for ternary rasterop.

Comment: new int[495616968] which is 1982467872 bytes.